# Why can't I debug MvvmLight Silverlight App

Tags: mvvm-light

I have created a default Mvvmlight silverlight 4, and it runs successfully displaying the app in the browser.

If I put a break point in the constructor of the MainPage, and debug the app, the debugger does not break. How do I configure this so I can debug the silverlight app?

Rgds
Douglas

Comment: This is a common question with various answers available throughout SO.

Comment: I haven't been able to find an answer in SO. I tried many seraches including "[mvvm-light] debug" and have not found the answer

Comment: Yep I am actually having the same problem right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a Web project and linked it to the mvvm silverlight app.

Also I am using firefox as default browser and there is a config tweak that needs to be done before the debugger can attach to firefox. see [Debugging Silverlight with VS and Firefox](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/16/enable-silverlight-debugging-in-firefox-visual-studio.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have been having another issue. Are you Attaching to the silverlight process? Just because you are debugging by hitting the button, doesnt mean you are attached to the silverlight process. This was a big change for me coming from a WPF/Windows Forms background.

Comment: Yes, that is sure to be the problem. When you create a default mvvmlight SL app, you do not get a Web App project created (just a single SL App project). There doesn't appear to be anything to attach the SL debugger to?

Comment: when you run the app though it should still open a webpage with your application running, you would still be able to open the attach to process screen and attach to the browser that has silverlight in its type column